# Yii2 | Получение данных с модели

Tags: php, yii2

День добрый. Начал изучать yii2.
Есть вопрос , не могу правильно получить данные с модели в контроллере.

код контроллера

```
public function actionChanelssetting(){
    if(isAdmin()){
        $model = app\models\ChanelsSetting::find()->count();// не получаются данные

        return $this->render('chanelssetting',[
         'model' => $model,   
        ]);
    }
    else{
     return $this->redirect(['site/index']);   
    }
}
```

код модели

```
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\base\Model;


class ChanelsSetting extends ActiveRecord{

    public static function tableName(){
        return '{{%chanelssetting}}';
    }

    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['id', 'active'], 'integer'],
            [['daily_limit_today ', 'daily_limit_tomorrow'], 'required'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Название',
            'slug' => 'Сокращенное название',
            'daily_limit_today' => 'Дневной лимит на сегодня',
            'daily_limit_tomorrow' => 'Дневной лимит на завтра',
        ];
    }

}
```

На выходе получаю ошибку. Если удалить строку с получением данных в контроллере,то вьюха работает, но без данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException' with message 'Headers already sent in /home/i/infowe8i/msg.webcom.mobi/models/ChanelsSetting.php on line 42.' in /home/i/infowe8i/msg.webcom.mobi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366
Stack trace:
#0 /home/i/infowe8i/msg.webcom.mobi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
#1 /home/i/infowe8i/msg.webcom.mobi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(135): yii\web\Response->send()
#2 /home/i/infowe8i/msg.webcom.mobi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException))
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException))
#4 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException' with message 'Headers already sent in /home/i/infowe8i/msg.webcom.mobi/models/ChanelsSetting.php on line 42.' in /home/i/infowe8i/msg.webcom.mobi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366
Stack trace:
#0 /home/i/infowe8i/msg.webcom.mobi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
#1 /home/i/infowe8i/msg.webcom.mobi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\web\Response->send()
#2 /home/i/infowe8i/msg.webcom.mobi/web/index.php(16): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}
```

Comment: нужен текст ошибки, которую получаете. как минимум. возможно дело даже не в самой этой строке а в процессах которые за счёт её запускаются

Comment: ну меня пишет просто "Ошибка №1", а как глубже копнуть я не знаю =(

Comment: надо включить отображение ошибок. если используете basic шаблон - файл web/index.php, если advanced шаблон - файл [frontend | backend]/web/index.php. примерно во второй строке вместо `define('YII_DEBUG', false)` поставить `define('YII_DEBUG', true)`, а вместо `define('YII_ENV', 'prod')` поставить `define('YII_ENV', 'dev')`

Comment: приложил скрин ошибки

Comment: Изменил немного , теперь класс нашелся, но другая ошибка

Comment: Все, победил, дело было в лишних пробелах в конце кода модели.....
Спасибо

Comment: ещё совет. в модели из функции rules нужно убрать в массиве все упоминания 'id'. оно там не нужно, id никогда не указывается в rules если в базе оно автоинкрементится. может в дальнейшем привести к ошибкам когда надо будет создавать/редактировать записи

Answer (score 1):

На вашем скриншоте с ошибкой сказано, что приложение не может найти класс `app\conttrollers\app\models\ChanelsSetting`.

Очевидно, что неверно указано FQCN (Fully Qualified Class Name) класса `ChanelsSetting`.

В вашем случае, вы забыли добавить знак `\` в начало имени класса, и PHP искал его в текущем namespase.

Подробнее о том, что произошло:

Контроллер находится в пространстве имён `app\controllers`.
В коде вы используете класс `app\models\ChanelsSetting`. Так как в начале нет знака `\`, PHP считает, что указано относительное имя, а потому добавляет в начало текущее пространство имён

```
app\controllers + app\models\ChanelsSetting = app\controllers\app\models\ChanelsSetting
```

Если бы вы указали `\` в начале (`\app\models\ChanelsSetting`) PHP посчитал бы имя абсолютным, и такого недоразумения не было бы.

Подробнее о том, как PHP работает с пространствами имён читайте тут:

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php